# angular + ngrx how to fetch data if component is already initialised

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

In my application I have a list of contacts that get loaded when the `/contacts` route loads and if a user clicks on a specific contact I load the child route `/contacts/view` which is supposed to display the detail of that contact.

When `/contacts/view/:id` loads for the first time (say /contacts/view/1), `ngOnInit()` gets triggered which dispatch a `LoadContact` action which is responsible of getting contact data from the server. However if I navigate to another contact clicking on another item on the list (say /contacts/view/2) the `ngOnInit()` doesn't get triggered and I'm unable to get data from the server.

Any idea on how I can make sure the view component always fetch fresh data from the server upon any kind of navigation (first load and subsequent navigations)?

Thanks,
Gab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Activated Route` for this

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = +params['id'];

       // dispatch action to load the details here.
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I was mistakenly using `this.route.snapshot` which doesn't return an observable therefore I wan't subscribing to the subsequent changes